# Text near to equations

Tags: spacing, algorithm2e

I am trying to get this:

[image]

My **problem** is the **space** **between** `null_array` and `[n][n]`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} %
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[noline,boxed]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

% real R
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tcolorbox}[blanker,width=(\linewidth-3.5cm)]
        \begin{algorithm}[H]
            \DontPrintSemicolon
    $\text{sim} = \text{null}\_\text{array}\left[n\right]\left[n\right] $ \\
$\text{sum\_prod} = \text{null}\_\text{array}\left[n\right]\left[n\right] $ \\
$\text{sum\_squ} = \text{null}\_\text{array}\left[n\right]\left[n\right] $ \\   
$\text{sum\_sqv} = \text{null}\_\text{araay}\left[n\right]\left[n\right] $ \\   
\caption{Tex Exchange}

        \end{algorithm}
    \end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

For above result you only need to remove all math stuff from your algorithm:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[noline,boxed]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

% real R
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tcolorbox}[blanker,width=(\linewidth-3.5cm)]
        \begin{algorithm}[H]
            \DontPrintSemicolon
sim = null array$[n][n]$\\
sum\_prod = null\_array$[n][n]$\\
sum\_squ = null\_array$[n][n]$\\
sum\_sqv = null\_araay$[n][n]$\\
\caption{Tex Exchange}
        \end{algorithm}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `n` is in math mode, though

Comment: than encapsulate it in `$` ... `$`, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Add a negative space (`\!`), as in `\text{null}\_\text{array}\!\left[n\right]`.